# Relationship between Cyclic group and Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let the $F$ is a field and $F^\#=F-\{0\}$

And $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $F$

It is definitely that

$F$ is a finite $\Rightarrow$  $F^\#$ is a cyclic group.

(IF $F$ is a just field, The above theorem is not true. Like the example $K=F(\alpha,\beta)$ since $K^\#$ is not cyclic.)

But the question is What if the case, the simple extension?

IF the $E=F(\alpha)$ is a simple extension of the F

Is it true '$E^\#$ is a cyclic group?

(I guess its counterexample is $Q(\sqrt 2))$, But Couldn't sure that my example is true.)

How do you think about that?

Any answer would help.

Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}(\sqrt{-1})$ and certainly $\mathbb{C}^*$ isn't cyclic.  Your own counterexample is fine, too.

Comment: Do you mean $F$ is a field?

Comment: Yes $F$ is a field

Comment: The word is "field" not "filed".

Comment: thanks. I just edited.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  If a field is finite, then it has cyclic multiplicative group.  If the field is infinite, then it does not.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No. Mr. @Randall caught my question and he answered. I've known the "If the field $F$ is finite extension of infinite field(like a $Q$), then It $F^\#$ is not a cyclic.". Are there any wrong the fact I've known Mr @lulu?

Comment: I don't understand why you keep bringing up extensions.  The multiplicative group of an infinite field is not cyclic.  Doesn't matter if you think of it as an extension of some other field or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem.** Let $F$ be a field. The multiplicative group of $F$ is cyclic if and only if $F$ is finite.

*Proof.* Suppose $F$ is finite of order $n$. The multiplicative group of $F$ is a finite abelian group, and so can be written (uniquely) as
$$F^*\cong C_{m_1}\oplus\cdots \oplus C_{m_k}$$
where $C_r$ is the cyclic group of order $r$, and we have $1\lt m_1$, $m_1|m_2|\cdots|m_k$ and $m_1m_2\cdots m_k = n-1$. We want to show that $k=1$.

In particular, every element of $F^*$ has multiplicative order dividing $m_k$, and hence the polynomial $x^{m_k}-1\in F[x]$ hs $n-1$ roots. Since $F$ is a field, the polynomial has at most $m_k$ roots, so $n-1\leq m_k\leq n-1$. Thus, $m_k=n-1$ which requires $k=1$, as claimed. That is, $F^*$ is cyclic.

Conversely, suppose that $F$ is infinite. If $F$ is of characteristic $p\gt 0$, then it contains a copy of the finite field with $p$ elements; this field contains an element of multiplicative order $p-1$ by Fermat’s Little Theorem, and so $F^*$ cannot be infinite cyclic. Thus, $F^*$ is not cyclic. If the characteristic of $F$ is $0$, then $F$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$. But then the multiplicative subgroup generated by $2$ and that generated by $3$ intersect trivially, which means that $F^*$ cannot be infinite cyclic (as any two nontrivial subgroups of the infinite cyclic group have nontrivial intersection). Thus, $F^*$ is not cyclic. $\Box$